# Change WebRequest for Image.Source

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, uwp

i need to provide a json as post request for authentication to get access to images in a Windows 10 app. I want to override the default behavior of Image.Source when it comes to loading Images from web to inject my json.

i have managed to override the default IWebRequestCreate handler for http:, https:, etc. however it is not getting called if Image.Source is set as URL, but it does get called for every other request. What am i doing wrong here?

This is my code to "inject" my IWebRequestCreate handler to the defaults.

```
public class UserImageWebRequest : IWebRequestCreate
{

    public WebRequest Create(Uri uri)
    {

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(uri.OriginalString))
        {
            if (uri.OriginalString.StartsWith("http://uxim.test.com/"))
            {
                string userId = WebUtility.UrlDecode(uri.OriginalString.Replace("http://uxim.test.com/", ""));

                return HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp("http://lorempixel.com/48/48/abstract");
            }
            else
            {
                if (uri.Scheme != null)
                {
                    var key = uri.Scheme + ":";

                    return GetDefaultCreatorForScheme(key).Create(uri);
                }
            }                
        }

        return null;
    }

    private static IWebRequestCreate GetDefaultCreatorForScheme(string scheme)
    {
        string key = "http:";

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(scheme))
        {
            string nkey = "";
            if (!scheme.EndsWith(":"))
                nkey = scheme + ":";
            else
                nkey = scheme;

            if (defaultCreators.ContainsKey(nkey))
                key = nkey;
        }

        return defaultCreators[key];
    }

    private static Dictionary<string, IWebRequestCreate> defaultCreators = new Dictionary<string, IWebRequestCreate>();
    public static void Register()
    {
        // a little bit reflection here in my life, a little bit of hacking by my side, a little bit of cheating is all i need!

        Type webRequest = typeof(System.Net.WebRequest);
        IList prefixList = (IList)webRequest.GetProperty("PrefixList", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic).GetValue(null, null);          

        IEnumerator enumerator = prefixList.GetEnumerator();
        while (enumerator != null && enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            var itemType = enumerator.Current.GetType();
            var fields = itemType.GetFields();
            var creatorField = fields.FirstOrDefault(A => A.Name == "Creator");
            var prefxField = fields.FirstOrDefault(A => A.Name == "Prefix");

            if (creatorField != null && prefxField != null)
            {
                // remember default creators
                defaultCreators.Add(
                    prefxField.GetValue(enumerator.Current) as string, 
                    creatorField.GetValue(enumerator.Current) as IWebRequestCreate);

                // override default creators
                creatorField.SetValue(enumerator.Current, new UserImageWebRequest());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Given you experience, it seems likely that the image GET requests aren't handled by the standard WebRequest code path.  Instead of using the interface, you may need to fetch the images in your own code and provide the image as an object rather than a string/URI. I used to do that with WPF, so I suspect the same would work in a UWP app.

Comment: It work for a UWP app, however it's not that smooth as using the build in behavior. Smoothness is all that matters, I don't want any stuttering in my UI.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean the result is not as smooth? I suspect your code isn't handling the request in the most effective manner. The other option that some might do would be to proxy the request as a GET method. It's somewhat atypical to need to POST for an image.

Comment: Yes, i know that it is atypical to need a POST, I've said that while the API was designed but I got ignored. Authentication via header would be a much better solution, but things are like they are, sadly. I'am currentliy trying to improve the way my Image loading works, I've created a own control, that can handle the request of the image on demand.